# Why was my answer deleted? Tried to explain that the problem is a bug that the software provider is fixing

Tags: discussion

Today I posted my first answer to a question, and my answer was deleted.

This question was asked today:
[UIWebView YouTube Embed video not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113104/uiwebview-youtube-embed-video-not-loading/)

I have the same problem as the questioner. It is a wide-spread problem, affecting many iOS apps with embedded YouTube videos.

I reported the problem to Google, as have other developers. Google has acknowledged that it is a bug and they are fast-tracking a fix.

How do I answer the question? I want to say, essentially, if you have existing apps with the problem, you don't have to do anything. Google is fixing it and here is a link to the defect. You're not alone, others are having the same problem. It's temporary.

Following is what I said. It was deleted by moderator [ChrisF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) with the comment, "While this is useful information, it's not a answer."

> Google is aware of the problem, and this is the issue they're using to track it: 
>   https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6061
>
> You can "star" it to be notified when Google has updates.

What would be the proper way to answer the question?

Thanks.

Comment: It ought to have been converted to a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't strictly speaking answer the question as it doesn't solve the problem posed in the question. It would however make a helpful comment.

Assuming you are correct and this is a known issue then a good answer might identify that and then go on to provide a work-around that avoids the problem (even if it is in a non ideal manner). Ultimately the general definition of an answer is "after reading and understanding the answer they no longer have the problem (or would not have the problem if the answer is correct)". If it doesn't fulfil this it should be a comment at most. In this case; having read and understood the post they know who to complain to but they still have the problem.